# Category and Subcategories OPT Group select in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have two three models:

- Announce
- Category
- Subcategory

This is my form.py

```py
# Formulaire de la depose d'une annonce
class AnnonceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label="", help_text="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Titre de mon annonce'}))
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Souscat.objects.all(), empty_label='Selectionnez une categorie', label="", help_text="", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Annonce
        fields = ('title','category')
```

And this is my models:

```py
# Catégories
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Catégorie"
        verbose_name_plural = "Catégories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# Sous catégories
class Souscat(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="s_category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Sous catégorie"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sous catégories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

On my annouce, i will get only subcategories, but on my select i want to show the categories and the subcategories can be selectable.
I have see this is possible with "optgroup", but i have successfull get all the subcategories on my but, i want to show the categories (not selectable) in my select with the subcategories (selectable).

For have the category i make simply {{ form.category }}

How can i make this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I had this same difficulty recently and I solved it with the guidance of this site.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/02/how-to-implement-grouped-model-choice-field.html

Basically, two classes were created that generate the code and make the magic happen! For me it worked perfectly.

Comment: It's always a good Idea to include some lines of code from the site linked, in case the site is moved or deleted.